# How to create custom assertions for collections in AssertJ

Tags: java, collections, assertj

There is an example on how to create custom assertions for custom classes in `AssertJ`:

http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-custom-assertions.html

But what about collections of custom classes?

How to create assertions for them?

Answer (score 3):

Two features exist for collection custom assertions :

- use a [specific element comparator + standard assertions collections](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#custom-comparison-strategy)
- use a [Condition to verify something on one or several collections elements](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html)

Hope it helps